# AJAX !Updating Higher Level DIV?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am using jQuery to trigger a few nested scripts.  I had expected the jQuery script to apply to the called scripts, but I have getting unexpected behavior - no update.  Here's the code for clarity:

```
        <div id="crnNav" class="centered">
            <?foreach ($CRNs as $crn) {
                echo '[<a href="pullCRN.php?crn='.$crn.'">'.$crn.']</a> ';  

            } unset($crn);?>
        </div>

        <div id="result">
            <!-- class data porn goes here -->
        </div>

<!-- controller logic -->
<script> // function updates content
   $('a').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $.get( href, function( data ) {
            $( "#result" ).load(href);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works as expected.  DIV #result populates with the contents of pullCRN.php, in fact since I have my selector as all anchors, it works for things I don't want.  But I have it there for testing purposes, because the code loaded by pullCRN.php generates more links.  What does not happen is #result does not update with the content of links loaded in pullCRN.php, only links outside of that DIV.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to rewrite the handler with the following syntax:

```
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

This tied my handler to new elements dynamically added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to place event as parameter

```
$('a').click(function(){//here and without parameter this wouldn't work
```

So, use this:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $.get( href, function( data ) {
            $( "#result" ).load(href);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @C-link, however, this code change has no apparent effect.  The function did work without the parameter, in all areas except for code generated inside the #result DIV.  Further, I am  new to the jQuery syntax, so I am not following where you may have been trying to lead with your answer.

Comment: EDIT: I found a conflicting script in the called element.  A quick fix looks like there is indeed a change in behavior.

Comment: Then use jQuery.noConflict(); too.

Comment: So adding the event parameter works while I maintain a universal selector.  When I change it to a multiple selector of the subclasses I want it stops function, the code does not even execute.  I know this because the links load as if they were pure HTML, the event.preventDefault(); is never being called. @C-link
       $('a.crn, a.snumber').click(function(event){

EDIT: a.crn is in the parent DOM, a.snumber is in the code previously called to the #result DIV

Comment: That's not the reason. Anyway try using event.stopPropagation or return false; last

Comment: event.stopPropagation() has no effect.  I know you said the link being at different levels is not the reason, and that makes sense, however, it may be worth noting that with the addition of the event parameter and the removal of lower level conflicting scripts, this currently still only works for the selectors that exist outside of the #result DIV only.